# SwiftData does not cascade delete relationship entries

Tags: ios, swift, swift-data

I'm trying to delete a parent along with its array of children. What happens is that the parent is deleted, but not the children in the array. The child just has its parent relationship set to null. If I change the `deleteRule` to `cascade` on the child and delete it, then the parent is deleted. So I'm a bit confused why it doesn't work the other way around.

Xcode 15.0.1 15A507
iOS 17.0 iPhone 15 Pro Simulator

**Model.swift**

```swift
import Foundation
import SwiftData
import SwiftUI

protocol Storeable {
    var timestamp: Date { get }
}

@Model
final class Child: Storeable {
    var timestamp: Date
    @Relationship(deleteRule: .nullify) var parent: Parent?
    
    init(timestamp: Date) {
        self.timestamp = timestamp
    }
}

@Model
final class Parent: Storeable {
    var timestamp: Date
    @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade, inverse: \Child.parent)
    var items: [Child]?

    init(timestamp: Date) {
        self.timestamp = timestamp
    }
}


final class StoreableItem: Storeable, Identifiable {
    var id: UUID
    var timestamp: Date
    var itemType: ItemType

    init<U>(storeable item: U) where U: Storeable {
        self.timestamp = item.timestamp
        self.id = UUID()
        
        switch item {
        case let i as Child: itemType = .child(i)
        case let m as Parent: itemType = .parent(m)
        default: itemType = .unknown
        }
    }
}

enum ItemType {
    case child(Child)
    case parent(Parent)
    case unknown
}
```

**AppFile.swift**

```swift
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

@main
struct stackoverflowApp: App {
    var sharedModelContainer: ModelContainer = {
        let schema = Schema([
            Parent.self, Child.self
        ])
        let modelConfiguration = ModelConfiguration(schema: schema, isStoredInMemoryOnly: false)

        do {
            return try ModelContainer(for: schema, configurations: [modelConfiguration])
        } catch {
            fatalError("Could not create ModelContainer: \(error)")
        }
    }()

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
        .modelContainer(sharedModelContainer)
    }
}
```

**ContentView**

```swift
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    @Query private var Childs: [Child]
    @Query private var Parents: [Parent]
    
    var allItems: [StoreableItem] {
        let mappedChilds = Childs.filter { $0.parent == nil }.map { StoreableItem(storeable: $0) }
        let mappedParents = Parents.map { StoreableItem(storeable: $0) }
        return mappedChilds + mappedParents
    }

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                ForEach(allItems) { item in
                    switch item.itemType {
                    case .child(let child):
                        Text("Child: \(child.timestamp.formatted())")
                            .swipeActions {
                                Button("Delete", role: .destructive) {
                                    modelContext.delete(child)
                                    try? modelContext.save()
                                }
                            }
                    case .parent(let parent):
                        Text("Parent: \(parent.timestamp.formatted())")
                            .swipeActions {
                                Button("Delete", role: .destructive) {
                                    modelContext.delete(parent)
                                    try? modelContext.save()
                                }
                            }
                    default: EmptyView()
                    }
                }
            }
            .listStyle(.plain)
            .toolbar {
                Button(action: add) {
                    Label("Add", systemImage: "plus")
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private func add() {
        withAnimation {
            let Parent = Parent(timestamp: Date())
            modelContext.insert(Parent)
            
            let child = Child(timestamp: Date())
            child.parent = Parent
            modelContext.insert(child)
        }
    }
}
```

`SortableItem` is a type erasing wrapper for the objects so I can render them in a list together.

[image]

Comment: You are creating two `Child` instances - One with a `Parent` and one that does not have a `Parent`.  Are you not just seeing the orphaned children?  A better approach is to create the `Parent` first, then create a new `Child` and set its `parent` property to the `Parent` you created.

Comment: Your code doesn't compile, some things are missing and/or some copy/paste mistake

Comment: Sorry about that. I have added the full code, simplified and tested working on Xcode. If you have time to check I would appreciate it.

Comment: Your `allItems` array is causing your problem.  Nothing updates it when your delete the parent

Comment: I'm not sure I understand sorry. If I create a parent with a child. I see a parent in my list. If I delete the parent, the parent disappears but the child pops up. This is because the parent of the child is now `nil` 
I can share a new gif of the example code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of problems; The first is the way you are putting two different object types into the `allItems` array - Because that array isn't observed by SwiftUI in any way, you will get strange and inconsistent updates.  For example, when I ran your code I saw parents appearing but not children (even though the child objects were being created as I could see when I added separate lists that use the `@Query` arrays directly).

But that isn't what is causing your deletion problem.  Even with separate `List`s I could see that the `Child` objects were not being deleted.

Switching from a `.swipeAction` to `onDelete` made the deletion work correctly -

```
List {
    ForEach(allItems) { item in
        switch item.itemType {
            case .child(let child):
                Text("Child: \(child.timestamp.formatted())")
                      
            case .parent(let parent):
                Text("Parent: \(parent.timestamp.formatted())")
            default: EmptyView()
        }
    }.onDelete(perform: { indexSet in
        for index in indexSet {
            let item = allItems[index]
            switch item.itemType {
                case .child(let child):
                    modelContext.delete(child)
                case .parent(let parent):
                    modelContext.delete(parent)
                default:
                    break
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Now, I can't tell you why this is.  In theory using a swipe action and deleting the object directly should work.

Comment: Sorry my design made that confusing. The children shouldn't appear if they have a parent. I want them to only show if they are unique which is why you wouldn't see it. But moving to the `onDelete` works perfectly. I don't really understand why but I won't question it! Thanks for the help Paul. Sorry, my post wasn't well detailed originally so I'll make sure they are going forward

Comment: Also the reason I was using swipe actions was because I might want to 'edit' a list via swipe, not sure they works alongside delete. But I can work around that. Cheers again!