# Swiftdata cascade deletion rule not working?

Tags: swift-data

I have the following code :

```swift
@Model
final class Parent {
    
    @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade)
    var children: [Child]

    init() {
        children = []
    }
}


@Model
final class Child {
    
    @Relationship(deleteRule: .nullify)
    var parent: Parent?

    init() {
        parent = nil
    }
}





struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var context
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            View1()
            Divider()
            View2()
            Divider()
            View3()
            Divider()
            View4()
        }
    }
    
    func View1() -> some View {
        // Works perfectly
        let parentFetch     = FetchDescriptor<Parent>()
        let childFetch      = FetchDescriptor<Child>()
        return Text("1 - Parents: \(try! context.fetchCount(parentFetch)) - Children: \(try! context.fetchCount(childFetch))")
    }
    
    func View2() -> some View {
        // Works perfectly
        let parentFetch     = FetchDescriptor<Parent>()
        let childFetch      = FetchDescriptor<Child>()
        
        let parent  = Parent()
        context.insert(parent)
        let child1  = Child()
        child1.parent   = parent
        let child2  = Child()
        child2.parent   = parent
        let child3  = Child()
        child3.parent   = parent
        
        return VStack {
            Text("2 - Parents: \(try! context.fetchCount(parentFetch)) - Children: \(try! context.fetchCount(childFetch))")
            Text("2 - Parent has: \(parent.children.count) children")
        }
    }
    
    func View3() -> some View {
        // Works perfectly
        let parentFetch     = FetchDescriptor<Parent>()
        let childFetch      = FetchDescriptor<Child>()
        
        let children        = try! context.fetch(childFetch)
        context.delete(children[0])
        try! context.save()
        
        let parent          = (try! context.fetch(parentFetch))[0]
        
        return VStack {
            Text("3 - Parents: \(try! context.fetchCount(parentFetch)) - Children: \(try! context.fetchCount(childFetch))")
            Text("3 - Parent has: \(parent.children.count) children")
        }
    }
    
    func View4() -> some View {
        // Just doesn't work
        let parentFetch     = FetchDescriptor<Parent>()
        let childFetch      = FetchDescriptor<Child>()
        
        let parent          = (try! context.fetch(parentFetch))[0]
        context.delete(parent)
        // Children won't be deleted !!!
        try! context.save()

        return VStack {
            Text("4 - Parents: \(try! context.fetchCount(parentFetch)) - Children: \(try! context.fetchCount(childFetch))")
        }
    }
}
```

When deleting the parent in View4(), I expect the children to be deleted too, as a consequence of the `.cascade` rule. But that's not the case, as shown here:

[image]

I have tried with and without specifying the inverse, with or with optional...

What's the trick, is that a known bug ? I found no trace of it.

Comment: It seems to be a bug. I found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77355653/swiftdata-does-not-cascade-delete-relationship-entries/77358961#77358961) that using a swipe-to-delete worked but not an explicit delete. There are also reports on Apple's developer forums - https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/740649 & https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/742166 for example

Comment: @JoakimDanielson There is only one delete rule per relationship.  There are two relationships here.  `.nullify` is the default, so even if you don't explicitly set it, there is still a delete rule. Anyway, I tried removing the `.nullify` and it still didn't work.

Comment: No, this is just Core Data.  There are two sides to a relationship, but they are separate relationships.  It is an error to explicitly specify two `inverse` values, but it is quite normal to have different delete rules for the two sides of a relationship.  For example, deleting a `School` deletes all `Students` but deleting a `Student` should not delete the `School`

Comment: @Paulw11 Ok I understand what you say so there must be a bug with .cascade then because all I see in the logs are how the relationship (foreign key) for the child objects being nullified. (In the database I see only one relationship so this made me believe you should only define one `@Relationship` in the swift code)

Answer (score 2):

OK, since it appears to be a bug in Swiftdata (I wonder how they could miss this one, but it seems Swiftdata is not mature, as I also found also two other obvious bugs), I propose the following work-around:

```swift
extension ModelContext {

    ///
    /// TODO:  BE REMOVED WHEN `.cascade` is fixed
    ///
    public func delete(parent: Parent) {
        for child in parent.children {
            self.delete(child)
        }
        self.delete(parent)
    }
}
```

Not ideal, as not API transparent, and also, you need to know you're deleting a parent.

But I'll accept any better workaround.

Comment: Thank you. Only think that worked for me. Didn't think about doing it manually.